# Is there some way to only show the PNG option in exporting.csv?

Tags: highcharts

I know that I can use menuItems: ["downloadPNG"], but I do not want to do that because I want the same styling that exporting.csv has. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.csv.columnHeaderFormatter I was reading about exporting.csv here, but didn't know how to omit the CSV and ViewTable portion. Basically, I want the below image to only have PNG as an option. [Dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfWvW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `menuItemDefinitions` property and define custom text, for example:

```
exporting: {
  menuItemDefinitions: {
    downloadPNG: {
      text: 'PNG'
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4903/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.menuItemDefinitions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to ommit the other options on your config file, like that:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        menuItems: [
          'downloadPNG'
        ]
      }
    },
```

Default exporting config is like that:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        menuItems: [
          'viewFullscreen', 'separator', 'downloadPNG',
          'downloadSVG', 'downloadPDF', 'separator', 'downloadXLS'
        ]
      }
    },
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your response! I was wondering if you knew how to get it to look like the image above? I have tried what you suggested previously, but when I do, instead of saying "PNG", it says "Download PNG image"

Comment: Ah, now I see what you meant, I found [this](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=34774) related topic, maybe it's going to solve your problem.